# Modify a client file

Tags: gdpr

After the setup of the GDPR law about personnal data security, I have a case I'm not sure about.
Test case: I receive an addresses file from a client containing x lines of addresses with personnal data (phone number, address, name,...).
I have a treatment to be ran on this file and I see that a data is incorrect (date format for example):
- Do I have the right to modify the original file?
- Should I ask the client to resend a new file?
- Can I change the format of the date if I make a copy of the file before?

Not really sure that case is concerned by the GDPR thought...

Answer (score 1):

No issue with how you modify the data. You still need to protect the original and modified data as personal data (though I know that's not your question).

And that's also assuming that the modifications you're making aren't reducing the accuracy of the personal data per Article 5... but I'm not sure why you'd want to update the data to be wrong.